# Dynamic menu from database in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm a beginner and I want to display menu on the left side like [This Website](https://www.daraz.pk/) and when user clicks on any Category Name or its Sub Category Name I want to display Products related to the clicked category.

I've created 4 tables in my database.

1. Category

   CategoryId(pk), CategoryName, Description, Icon
2. SubCategory

   SubCategoryId(pk), SubCategoryName, Description, Icon,CategoryId(fk)
3. SubSubCategory

   SubSubCategoryId(pk), SubSubCategoryName, Description, Icon, SubCategoryId(fk)
4. Products

   ProductId(pk), Name, Price, Description, CategoryId(fk), SubCategoryId(fk), SubSubCategoryId(fk)

**Category.cs Model**

```
public partial class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        Products = new HashSet<Product>();
        SubCategories = new HashSet<SubCategory>();
    }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Icon{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
}
```

**SubCategory.cs**

```
public partial class SubCategory
{
    public SubCategory()
    {
        Products = new HashSet<Product>();
        SubSubCategories = new HashSet<SubSubCategory>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string SubCategoryName { get; set; }
    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Icon{ get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubSubCategory> SubSubCategories { get; set; }
}
```

**SubSubCategory.cs**

```
public partial class SubSubCategory
{
    public SubSubCategory()
    {
        Products = new HashSet<Product>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int SubSubCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string SubSubCategoryName { get; set; }
    public int? SubCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }
}
```

**Product.cs**

```
public partial class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int? SubCategoryId { get; set; }
    public int? SubSubCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: And where is the controller and the view ? Did you make any ?

Comment: you should first try it on your own by doing some research on various tutorial sites. And if still things are not working as they should, then post a question. This just seems like you don't want to try and want us to do it for you!!

Comment: I searched about this, they were using only 1 table in tutorials. like Menu Table with only MenuId, MenuName, Url, ParentId . but I have 3 tables for menu

Comment: And why do you need three tables for this?

Comment: @Style its categories and subcategories like Clothing > Mens Clothing > T-shirts

Answer (score 0):

You should try to first load the whole collection that you want to use in the current view.

Then use lambda expressions or predicates to sort the data into categories e.g

```
var list = wholeList.Where(i => i.category == "{category-name}");
```

then load this list to the view templates.

This method is both fast and convenient

Answer (score -1):

On Click of Category, SubCategory, Sub Sub Category,
You should try below MVC way to load partials. Use appropriate overload of this.

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink( ....)
```

- Remember to use targetId in which element your called partial will load.
- Your Layout must include jquery and jquery.unobtrusive-ajax. (jquery version must be higher than 1.9)